# Is there any Visual Studio extension to “favorite” folders and files?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions, visual-studio-extensions, solution-explorer

I'm working on a middle-sized project that contains several class libraries, database model and an ASP .NET MVC website project. However, even though there are less than 15 projects in the solution, **I often find myself collapsing and expanding endless folders to find a certain class or view**.

While looking for class is mostly solved by Resharper [type navigation feature](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/navigation_search.html#Go_to_Type), I often want to switch to a certain view in MVC project. I don't remember the file name and it wouldn't solve the problem either because there are many views with same file name (e.g. `Message\ViewSingle.cshtml`, `Product\ViewSingle.cshtml`).

What I'd rather want is **an ability to “favorite” certain files, projects or folders so they are displayed on a separate Solution Explorer-like window** for quick access.

Is there such an extension available (for free)?

#### Update

@samy [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858665/is-there-any-visual-studio-extension-to-favorite-folders-and-files/6858732#6858732) that [Sergey Vlasov](http://www.svprogramming.net/)'s [Favorite Documents](http://www.svprogramming.net/favorite-documents/index.html) extension allows for quick access **via the menubar**,  I usually tend to [hide it](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bdbcffca-32a6-4034-8e89-c31b86ad4813) and would prefer a dockable window solution so I'm still looking. I wrote Sergey to find out if he plans to work on this functionality.

#### Update (Aug 4th)

I just received a letter from Sergey in which he points me to Favorite Documents 1.1 got a dedicated window. Therefore I accept [samy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858665/is-there-any-visual-studio-extension-to-favorite-folders-and-files/6858732#6858732).

Comment: Great news, and Kudos to Sergey indeed for being so reactive :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're in luck, [this Favorite Documents extension](http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.com/2011/07/this-is-my-favorite-vs-2010-favorites.html) is just out. I found it via the [Morning Brew](http://blog.cwa.me.uk/).

[Favorite Documents by Sergey Vlasov](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d4ab8421-147f-4416-8038-d5f7fdcf6a56)

> The free Favorite Documents extension lets you create links to
> frequently used code files and then quickly open them as a group or
> individually from the Favorites menu in Visual Studio 2010

#### Update

After being contacted about this thread, Sergey rolled out version 1.1 with [several improvements](http://www.svprogramming.net/favorite-documents/whats_new.html) and a dedicated window (as requested in question).

[image: Favorite Documents by Sergey Vlasov]

Comment: This is an amazing coincidence, as it just came out two days ago and we both happen to be Russian :-). However this extension works via top menu, rather than via a dockable window. I usually tend to hide the main menu and it is still cumbersome to go there for the sake of navigating to a fave. I will email Sergey now and find out if he has  any plans to work on a dockable window for the extension. Thanks!

Comment: I just thought of maybe writing something like this to play around with vs extensions. GREAT to know it exists. tnx

Comment: It's 2016 and now is just when I've discovered this extension. What a life saver for large projects.

Comment: @JohnK. It's never too late for great tools :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use Libraries on Windows Vista or Seven, and organize folders as you wish. Maybe is not complete solution for your problem, but just to mention that :)

Comment: If you mean creating libraries that "accumulate" files from different folders, I see your point. However I'm working on a project with a team of developers. How would libraries behave with SVN? TFS?

Comment: Well, you could use new Library API to create libraries from some file or other resource that will describe it, here are some url to do so : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd861346.aspx, http://www.grimadmin.com/article.php/creating-modifying-windows-7-libraries