# Is there a plugin for creating a custom (named) scope in visualstudio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Does someone know if there is a solution explorer plugin available to create a named scope for some certain related project files? For instance, i am working on multiple functionalities for a website and over a day I often switch between does functionalities. This means that i have to open all the related files again which gets very anoying over time. So basically i would like to open all the files related to a certain functionality and create a named scope for it.

```
Scope name: basket

files: 
website project
includes\script\basket.js
includes\css\basket.css
webparts\basket.ascx

Dataservice project
datalayer\basketservice.cs

Test project
tests\baskettest.cs
```

There is alread a "Scope to this" function in the solution explorer but that let's me only scope to a specific folder.

I hope you get the idea!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858665/is-there-any-visual-studio-extension-to-favorite-folders-and-files

Comment: @SergeyVlasov: Spasibo! Exactly what is was looking for!